# How to check if a RxJS Observable contains a string in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am new to Angular2 and Observable, I want to check if a Observable `getRoles` which is of type `Observable<string[]>` contains a string.

```
public hasRole(name: string): boolean {
    // getRoles is of type Observable<string[]>
    let getRoles = this.tokenService.getTokenInformation().map(element => element.roles);

    if (/* check if name is inside of getRoles */) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observables are asynchronous so you can't use `let getRoles = ...map(...)`. The [`map()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) method is not executed on an array but on an Observable which is always asynchronous.

So proper way to do it could be (I didn't test this code):

```
public hasRole(name: string): Observable {
    return this.tokenService.getTokenInformation()
        .map(element => element.roles)
        .first(roles => roles.indexOf(name) !== -1);
}
```

Operator [`first()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first) emits an error when no matching element was found when the source completed (when we iterated all roles).

Then use this method like:

```
hasRole('my-role').subscribe(
    role => console.log("has role"),
    error => console.log("doesn't have role"),
)
```

Edit:

This converts everything to only `true` or `false` values. See doc for `first()` operator what are these argument. Then I used `map()` to force convert everything into boolean.

```
public hasRole(name: string): Observable {
    return this.tokenService.getTokenInformation()
        .map(element => element.roles)
        .first(roles => roles.indexOf(name) !== -1, undefined, false)
        .map(val => !!val);
}
```

See live simplified demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/MtYfGLgqgHACPswFTVJ5

Comment: I get a error, it should be hasRole(...):Observable<string[]>. But is it possible to get somehow a boolean return type ? Because what I want is to know if the Observable contains my string ?

Comment: @Devid When `console.log("has role")` is called then the role was among `roles`. When `console.log("doesn't have role")` is called then it wasn't. If you really want to receive only `true` of `false` see my update.

Comment: @Martin OP is expecting to return a bool from his method.. just change the method such way that it should return a `bool` that's it.. (*after adding comment you did edit, it has that thing covered. COOL!*) +1

Comment: @Martin thanks for the help. Although now it is a bit tricky. I will test it and then accept your answer. ps. Do you know a good tutorial where I can get warm with promise and observable ?

Comment: @Devid I'd personally recommend the official doc on their github repo. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/doc. In particular https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/introduction.md and https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/observable.md